# NativeScript Http module getscript return and assign response to variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, nativescript

How do I send an HTTP GET or POST request to a server and assign the return value to a variable?  The NativeScript docs offer the following:

```
httpModule.getString("https://httpbin.org/get").then((r) => {
    viewModel.set("getStringResult", r);
}, (e) => {
});
```

The documentation isn't clear on what is in r, or what viewModel is.  I am looking to simply capture an AJAX request that would be simple in jQuery. example:

```
let returnVal
$.post(url,function(d) { returnVal = d }
```

Comment: As by the method name, it returns the response body as string.

Comment: @Manoj that doesn't help at all.

Comment: So does it become `d - httpModule...` or `d = viewModel.set...` or....?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. It's just a promise that returns a string in body. In your jQuery sample you are doing `returnVal = d` which is same as `viewModel.set("getStringResult", r);` but here you are assigning it on ViewModel instead of simple variable. If you are building app with Core template, ViewModel could be reference to your Observable instance.

Comment: Could be this, if you just looking for just an equivalent `httpModule.getString("https://httpbin.org/get").then((d) => {
    returnVal = d
}, (e) => {
});`

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question - on the jQuery snippet, I meant to have the declaration `let returnVal` not `return d` - that was a mistake.

Comment: @Manoj That did the trick.  If you could post that as an answer instead of a comment, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by the method name, `httpModule.getString(...)` returns the response body as string. ViewModel is generally referred to the Observable instance of your View / Page.

So `r` here carries string returned by the end point, you may simply assign it to any variable.

```
httpModule.getString("https://httpbin.org/get").then((d) => {
   returnVal = d;
}, (e) => {
});
```